# Correlation of Error terms

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, correlation

The following text is from statistical learning by  Trevor and Tibshirani.  I added my own question inside bracket and mentioned what i want to learn? Please take a look and provide your useful suggestions.

> If there is correlation among the error terms, then the estimated
>   standard errors will tend to underestimate the true standard errors.
>    (How does it happen ?)
>
> As a result, conﬁdence and prediction intervals will be narrower than
>   they should be. (Clear)
>
> For example, a 95% conﬁdence interval may in reality have a much lower
>   probability than 0.95 of containing the true value of the
>   parameter. (What does this mean)
>
> In addition, p-values associated with the model will be lower than
>   they should be  (How? can you provide example ?);
>
> this could cause us to erroneously conclude that a parameter is
>   statistically signiﬁcant.  In short, if the error terms are correlated,
>   we may have an unwarranted sense of conﬁdence in our model.?*

and the last part

> observations that are obtained at adjacent time points will have
>   positively correlated errors. (Why it is happening ? )

Comment: I think an answer to a similar question can help those who bump into this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957686/explain-about-the-correlation-of-error-terms-in-linear-regression-models